# Do bigcommerce provide single user sandbox accounts for developers?

Tags: bigcommerce

Do bigcommerce provide single user sandbox accounts for developers? I know they have open accounts with lots of developers on them, but I am looking for an individual account.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a design or development partner, you will get access to a partner sandbox account.

Not a development partner yet? Here's how you can apply to be one. http://www.bigcommerce.com/partners

Comment: This is super annoying to wait just to test out with basic api functionality. Should only need partner status for submitted apps, what's the point of having the rest of the 'developer' area available wihout being a partner if you can't do anything with it.